# Is it possible to see deployment history logs at Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I don't even know if such logs exist but it could be useful to see. Other than that, the title is quite self explanatory.

Comment: It's 2018, and I can't find this information. I would love to know the new way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the admin logs section in the admin console.  It contains all kinds of deployment operations.  You can filter by selecting the 'All Version changes' option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Looked for this in 2018 - these logs can now be easily found in the Cloud Builder:
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build